# Gradient not work in firefox

Tags: html, css

Gradient effect work in chrome but not in firefox and IE .. here is gradient css code

```
.large-thumb { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
  from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)), to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-
  stop(.5,#333333)); 
  width: 291px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  bottom: 31px;
  -moz-border-radius:25px;
  -webkit-border-radius:25px;
  border-radius:25px;
}
```

for more demo see [demo blog site](http://infinitytechs.blogspot.in)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the moz extension and a filter for older versions of IE.

[See this page.](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```
.large-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32)', endColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',GradientType=0 );
  width: 291px;
  background: transperent;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

You also might want to look at [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE support.

## Update

I updated my code example to use RGBA values in the gradient which gives you a transparent gradient on modern browsers. It should fall back to solid colors on newer older browsers.

[See this page for support details](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: I use given code.. but there are problem when apply opacity, i wanna use opacity only for background gradient ,not for text over gradient.. you can see demo blog applied that css .. btw thanks. hope for solve this query

Comment: @NildevVaghela Can you create a JSBin or JSFiddle that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: no dude.. if u need demo.already i post link of blog.btw thanks whoacowboy

Comment: There is a lot going on and it is difficult to see what you trying to do specifically. If you isolate the issue, it will be easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

That vendor prefix is specific to Webkit based browsers. All browsers now support unprefixed gradients, like so:

```
linear-gradient:([angle],[colours])
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients for full spec.